# Converting a jQuery Deferred Promise to a native JavaScript Promise

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, jquery-deferred

I plucked this JavaScript code below out of a library and it uses jQuery's Deferred/promises which are not the same as the official Promise spec.

I would like to convert this basic example into a Native JavaScript Promise while keeping the same format/structure below.

Almost every example Promise usage I find online is of loading something asynchronously and I have some cases where I would like to use them for other tasks and this example does just that!

- `App.show()` is called
- `App.show()` calls a function that returns a `Promise` `App.Animations.swipe.apply(this, [current, next, dir]).then(finalize);`
- The promise function has an event handler function inside it that runs when a CSS animation is completed and that triggers the Promise to resolve.
- When the promise resolves it then calls the `finalize` function that is inside of the `App.show()` function.

It might be easier to follow what it does by simply looking at the example below....

```
var App = {

  show: function(index, direction) {
    var $this = this;

    // called after Promise is resolved with .then(finalize)
    finalize = function() {
      // other code here ran now after promise resolved from App.Animations.swipe()....
    };

    // call function which returns a Promise
    Animations.swipe.apply(this, [current, next, dir]).then(finalize);
  },


  Animations = {

    'none': function() {
      var d = UI.$.Deferred();
      d.resolve();
      return d.promise();
    },

    // function returns a Promise which has an event handler inside it that resolves the promise
    'swipe': function(current, next, dir) {

      var d = UI.$.Deferred();

      next.css('animation-duration', this.options.duration + 'ms');

      // Event handler ran one time when CSS Animation ends and triggers the event
      // this event is what resolves the promise
      next.css('opacity', 1).one(UI.support.animation.end, function() {

        current.removeClass(dir === -1 ? 'uk-slideshow-swipe-backward-out' : 'uk-slideshow-swipe-forward-out');
        next.css('opacity', '').removeClass(dir === -1 ? 'uk-slideshow-swipe-backward-in' : 'uk-slideshow-swipe-forward-in');
        d.resolve();

      }.bind(this));

      // return a Promise Object when this function is called
      return d.promise();
    },
  }
};
```

---

So based on that code how can it be converted to not use jQuery's Deferred and use native JS Promises?

Comment: What you are asking for here is not recommended. Native Promises will assimilate jQuery promises but jQuery promises will not assimilate native Promises. Therefore, in a jQuery environment, low level promisifications such as `.swipe()`, should return a jQuery promise to ensure its assimilation by a jQuery promise chain or `jQuery.when()` higher in the call stack. You will get away with returning a native promise as long as `.show()` (as currently written) is the only caller. However, if `.swipe()` is called elsewhere, you *could* run into trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'none': function() {
  var d = UI.$.Deferred();
  d.resolve();
  return d.promise();
},
```

That's a simple one

```
'none': function() {
    return Promise.resolve();
},
```

Now for swipe:

```
'swipe': function(current, next, dir) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    next.css('animation-duration', this.options.duration + 'ms');

    // Event handler ran one time when CSS Animation ends and triggers the event
    // this event is what resolves the promise
    next.css('opacity', 1).one(UI.support.animation.end, function() {

      current.removeClass(dir === -1 ? 'uk-slideshow-swipe-backward-out' : 'uk-slideshow-swipe-forward-out');
      next.css('opacity', '').removeClass(dir === -1 ? 'uk-slideshow-swipe-backward-in' : 'uk-slideshow-swipe-forward-in');
      resolve();

    }.bind(this));
},
```

### Notes

I just want to add that jQuery Promises (or Deferreds as they call them) were at one stage kind of broken, but these days I think they are compliant with Promise/A+ spec.

Many jQuery functions (ajax, animations for example) return a promise, or you can return `.promise()` - which negates the need for what I've done in the answer, and that is to use a promise constructor anti-pattern.

I'm not sure enough about your code to know if any of those jQuery methods can return a promise or not.

Comment: Perfect I knew it was simple but wasn't sure.  I made a demo here using a Click event to resolve the Promise for future reference https://jsfiddle.net/jasondavis/pjvd39kk/ thanks

Comment: @JasonDavis - I just added some comments which may be worth reading

Comment: Thanks I will read up on jQuery again as its been a while since I checked the status of there promises.  As for the demo it is only using jQuery for some click events and dom selectors its just to get the concept of a non asynchronous promise usage.  Just experimenting!  thanks for the help